# Unable to disting the record in Link Expression

Tags: asp.net, linq, telerik-open-access

I have two tables: `TblAppointmentTypes` and `TblEmployeeInfo`. There is many to many relation between these two tables with a joined table that is `TblEmployeeServices`. There are two records in `TblAppointmentTypes` and four records in `TblEmployeeInfo`. All the two records of `TblAppointmentTypes` is assigned to all of the records in `TblEmployeeInfo`, that there is eight records in `TblEmployeeServices`. I want to retrive all the services that are assigned to all the four `Employees`, it should return 2 that is assigned to all the four employees, but my query return 8 records, four duplicate services.

I am using Telerik Open Access ORM. Here is the code:

```
public static List<TblAppointmentType> GetAllAppointmentType(List<int> employeeIDs)
{
    var list = new List<TblAppointmentType>();
    if (employeeIDs != null && employeeIDs.Count > 0)
    {
        var dc = new Entities();
        list = (from a in dc.TblAppointmentTypes.Distinct()
               join e in dc.TblEmployeeServices on a.ID equals e.AppointmentTypeID
               where a.IsDeleted == false && employeeIDs.Contains<int>(e.EmployeeID)
               select a).ToList();
     }
     return list;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I figured it out, You want to get all AppointmentTypes which are related to all Employees. 
It means that AppTypes that are related to 3 Employees (in your case) should be excluded.
So, the most efficient code that I have tried is like this :

```
list = (from a in dc.TblAppointmentTypes
               join e in dc.TblEmployeeServices on a.ID equals e.AppointmentTypeID
               where a.IsDeleted == false 
               group e.EmployeeID by a into g
               where g.count() == employeeIDs.Count()
               select g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, but this code did not worked for me, it throws this exception:

An exception occured during the execution of 'Extent<Model.TblAppointmentType>().Join(Extent<Model.TblEmployeeService>(), a => a.ID, e => e.AppointmentTypeID, (a, e) => new <>f__AnonymousType8`2(a = a, e = e)).Where(<>h__TransparentIdentifier2e => (<>h__TransparentIdentifier2e.a.IsDeleted == False)).GroupBy